# On scrolling of table view, corner radius of label is getting distorted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have one label in view, which on basis of some condition will be visible for some rows. I have added label in stack view. UI of label is to have background color and corner radius as round.

I have sub class UItableview cell and have used following code:

```
class SampleCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.status.text = nil
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func setUpStatusLabel(isShow: Bool) {
        self.status.text = "Status"

        self.status.textColor = UIColor.red
        self.status.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        self.status.layer.cornerRadius = 
        self.status.frame.size.height/2
        self.status.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.status.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.status.isHidden = !isShow
    }
}
```

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sample", for: indexPath) as? SampleCell)!
if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.setUpStatusLabel(isShow: true)
        } else {
            cell.setUpStatusLabel(isShow: false)
        }
}
```

When I launch this code and scrolls table view, corner radius of label sometimes becomes in such a way to show rectangle view meaning no corner radius and sometimes background color is also lost. I need to retain all of this when user scrolls the table view.

Comment: how and where are you calling `setUpOrderStatusLabel`?

Comment: kindly share a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your UI for both the cases of `isShow`:

```
func setUpStatusLabel(isShow: Bool) {
    self.status.isHidden = !isShow
    self.status.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.status.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    self.status.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)

    if isShow {
        self.status.text = "Status"
        self.status.textColor = UIColor.red
        self.status.layer.cornerRadius = self.status.frame.size.height/2
    } else {
        //change the following according to your need.

        self.status.text = ""
        self.status.textColor = UIColor.darkText
        self.status.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I clean and ran my code again. Everything started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this in cellForRowAt indexPath 
cell.selectionStyle = .none